# How to achieve dynamic columnmapping in azure data factory when Dynamics CRM is used as sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I have a requirement where i need to pass the column mapping dynamically from a stored procedure to the copy activity. This copy activity will perform update operation in Dynamics CRM. The source is SQL server (2014) and sink is Dynamics CRM.

I am fetching the column mapping from a stored procedure using look up activity and passing this parameter to copy activity.'

When i directly provide the below mentioned json value as default value to the parameter, the copy activity is updating the mapped fields correctly.

{"type":"TabularTranslator","columnMappings":{"leadid":"leadid","StateCode":"statecode"}}

But when the json value is fetched from the SP , it is not working . I am getting the error ColumnName is read only.

Please suggest if any conversion is required on the output of the loopup activity before passing the parameter to copy activity. Below is the output of the lookup activity.

{\"type\":\"TabularTranslator\",\"columnMappings\":{\"leadid\":\"leadid\",\"StateCode\":\"statecode\"}}

Appreciate a quick turnaround.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter directly and Using lookup output are different. can you share how did you write the parameter from the output of lookup actvitiy.
you can refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity